# How to disable magic number using OAuthPrompt in bot framework V4

Tags: c#, authentication, oauth-2.0, botframework, direct-line-botframework

I had implemented authentication to my bot application by referring [here](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/tree/master/samples/csharp_dotnetcore/24.bot-authentication-msgraph). I had successfully implemented and able to sign in but application is authenticating user using magic number. Is not there any way to disable magic number?

**Note:** I had created bot application using Bot Framework V4

Comment: authentication with which provider?

Comment: Which channel are you connecting your bot to? Teams, Facebook and Slack channels require magic code signin flow.

Comment: I am connecting to direct line channel.

Comment: Can you post your code as to what you have implemented so far? Just to be clear, are you implementing a custom direct line solution or implementing Web Chat using direct line ?

Comment: I am using web chat using direct line. Code is extracted from github sample. I never changed even single part of code except connection name.

Answer (score 1):

There have been improvements to the channels to support new authentication features, such as new WebChat and DirectLineJS libraries to eliminate the need for the 6-digit magic code verification. You can follow these links to prevent the magic code from showing up:

- https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder/issues/4632#issuecomment-441957719( refer to @compulim's comment here, who is the developer of Web Chat and has specified the steps to eliminate the magic code flow).
- https://github.com/Microsoft/BotFramework-WebChat/pull/1218( pull request for the token server sample).