# How to authenticate Bot without Magic Code

Tags: botframework

How can I disable **Magic Code** in Bot Framework version 4 (direct like channel).

Has anyone run into the same problem?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to disable magic number using OAuthPrompt in bot framework V4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55917494/how-to-disable-magic-number-using-oauthprompt-in-bot-framework-v4)

Comment: duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57496672/aad-authentication-directline-teams-disable-security-code/57500846#57500846 & https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57053009/magic-code-while-oauth-using-botframework-any-way-around